# React native: How to set icon on the app switch screen on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

On other screens, all horse trams are displayed well. View picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0dsb.png

Comment: hi, u fixed it? same problem but cant figure it out ( only on iOS ) expo 44

Answer (score 0):

For Expo:

That basically your AppIcon you can configure your App Icon and a splash Screen inside your:

```
app.json
```

Looks like this for Expo for example:

```
"version": "1.0.11",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/AppIcon.png",   // This is the ICON !! 
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/NewFinal.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#FE0000"
},
```

For Normal React Native check this:

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-change-app-icon/
or
https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-add-app-icons-and-launch-screens-onto-ios-and-android-apps-3bfbc20b7d4c

Comment: I saw second link but it works only for launch icons in the base menu and it does not work for switch app screen. Rebuild also tried.